# Bootstrap 4.0 Beta alignment of button group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I've got a `<div>` I've declared in Bootstrap 4.0 that I'm using to fill up a row of buttons that fill the div horizontally. I've tried declaring the `btn-group` elements as both `<buttons>` and `<a role="button">`, but either way I try, I'm getting the left-most button out of alignment:

[image]

Using the `<a>` approach, I'm declaring the div like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" id="hours-and-location">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" role="button">button</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" role="button">button</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" role="button">button</a>
</div>
```

Declaring them as `<buttons>` looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified align-self-center" id="hours-and-location">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block h-100">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block h-100">Button 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block h-100">Button 3</button>
</div>
```

I've tried setting margin, padding, adding !important in CSS, and I've been through a ton of CSS posts. I've looked at the elements in Firefox's inspection utilities and I can't see why they're out of alignment.

I welcome additional ideas re: how to resolve this. At the end of the day, I just want some buttons to fill a div. If there's a simpler Bootstrap way of doing it without overriding a ton of CSS, I'm all ears. Thank you for reading.

As I type this, I neglected to add my CSS and the problem cropped up without my CSS (So I've wasted a lot of time debugging CSS ).

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<br>
<br>
<br>
<section class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row vertical-center">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- <div class="row my-auto"> -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">

          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified align-self-center" id="hours-and-location">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block h-100">Button 2</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block h-100">Button 2</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block h-100">Button 3</button>
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" id="hours-and-location">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" role="button">button</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" role="button">button</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" role="button">button</a>
        </div> -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Bootstrap4 uses flexbox which is not supported by ie8 or ie9.  (Just a heads up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertical alignment is off because of the `btn-block` class - remove `btn-block` from *all* of your buttons.

`btn-block` is meant for `button`s that come one below the other (hence there is a *default* `margin-bottom` between them) - see doc excerpts below:

> Create block level buttons—those that span the full width of a
>   parent—by adding .btn-block.
>
> [bootstrap-4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/#sizes)

Also for the *wrapper* of the buttons, `align-self-center` has no meaning as it is meant for *flex items* (the parent is not a `flexbox` either in the code). It should be assigned to *each* flex item, or you can just give `algin-items-center` class.

See demo below:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<br>
<br>
<br>
<section class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row vertical-center">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- <div class="row my-auto"> -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">

          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified align-items-center" id="hours-and-location">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary h-100">Button 2</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary h-100">Button 2</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary h-100">Button 3</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome! What would you use to get the buttons to evenly fill the div they presently occupy?

Comment: you can add `w-100` class to `#hours-and-location` and add the style `#hours-and-location > button {
  flex: 1!important;
}`